# I can not hook into wpcf7_mail_sent in my custom plugin php class

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

In my Wordpress plugin, I have a php class in which I want to hook into the contact form 7 hook `wpcf7_mail_sent`. But it does not work for me.

the do_something() does not come in to the hook process.

I guess that I have registered that hook in a wrong place (`__construct()`).

Could you please help me?

```
<?php

class MyCF7 {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', array( $this, 'do_something' ) );

    }

    public function do_something() {

    }
}
```

**Expansion :**

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Contact Form 7 - My plugin
Description: My Integration
Version: 1.0
*/

class MyCF7 {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', array( $this, 'do_something' ) );
    }

    public function activate() {
        // add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', array( $this, 'do_something' ) );
        // This hook would not be registered in activate() method.
    }

    public function do_something( $contact_form ) {
        error_log( 'do_something was triggered.' );
        // Header( 'Location: https://google.com' );
    }
}

$my_cf7 = new MyCF7();
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $my_cf7, 'activate' ) );
```

Now my question is: How can i redirect to an url when a contact form is submitted?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to put action hooks in the class constructor, gives you a really tightly coupled code, plus every time you instantiate a class, you have an action call. Also are you instantiating your class at all? As a last resort see if increasing the priority of that hook will work.

Comment: Thank you @dingo_d. Yes I've instantiated my class and other hooks are working in the instantiated object.

Comment: @dingo_d Also increasing the priority of that hook didn't work.

Comment: @dingo_d I have an `activate()` member function and have registered it via `register_activation_hook`. I added hook `wpcf7_mail_sent` in the `activate()` method, but it did not work too. After that I added it to the `__construct()` .

Comment: @dingo_d I think i made a mistake. In the `activate()` method it will not be triggered, but be triggered in the `__construct()`. Now , I  want to redirect to a custom url, but it does not redirect in the `__construct()`.

Comment: Can you expand your original question with examples, that will make it more clear to what you are doing :)

Comment: @dingo_d Yes. I expanded my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am inspired from [Contact Form 7 redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/) plugin and solved my problem.

As the Contact Form 7 Module handles it's form submission by javascript, I must add a javascript event listener and enqueue that js file to my Wordpress javascript files.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Contact Form 7 - My plugin
Description: My Integration
Version: 1.0
*/

class MyCF7 {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->plugin_url       = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_frontend' ) );
    }

    public function enqueue_frontend() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpcf7-redirect-script', $this->plugin_url . 'js/wpcf7-redirect-script.js', array(), null, true );
    }
}
```

wpcf7-redirect-script.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    wpcf7_redirect_mailsent_handler()
})

function wpcf7_redirect_mailsent_handler () {
    document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
        location.href = 'https://google.com'
    }, false)
}
```

Sorry I should have asked this question in another way.

Comment: I think the problem still remains. If I want to redirect to a dynamic url, what shall I do?